Are Word Lists (Anagrams) in Games Like Wordscapes or WoW Protected by Copyright?
I have developed a word puzzle game similar to Wordscapes and Words of Wonders (WoW) and want to determine whether my level creation process falls within fair use or if it might violate copyright laws.
Here’s my process:

I think of a base word, such as "ELBOW."
I use public game answer websites like "Words of Wonders Answers" to
search for this word.
The website shows that "ELBOW" is featured in
WoW level 347. When I click on that level, it provides a list of
anagrams used in that specific level (e.g., BELOW, ELBOW, BLEW,
BOWL, etc.).
I copy this word list from the website to make my game levels. Sometimes i edit the word list by removing or adding more words, either from another source or by thinking of them myself.
Then I put those words to the crossword board, using my own layout arrangement, not replicating WoW board arrangement.However, I arrange the crossword board layout myself and do not replicate WoW board.

I have already created and published 100+ levels for my game using this process.
At the time, I used this method because it was difficult to find a complete dictionary word list in My Language (My game is not in English Language). And the WoW Answers site made it easier to gather anagrams. Now i have my own Anagram Generator using Wiktionary wordlist data, but the levels already published were created using the described process.
My questions are:

Are the word lists (anagrams) featured in games like Wordscape, WoW, or shown
on answer websites, protected under copyright law?
Does copying such
a word list from a website that explicitly attributes it to a
specific game level (e.g., WoW level 347) constitute copyright
infringement?
Since anagram word lists are inherently constrained by the structure and rules of the base word (e.g., letters must rearrange into valid words), and their results are often predictable (e.g., 1000 people generating anagrams for "ELBOW" would produce similar results), does this make them less eligible for copyright compared to arbitrary word lists that are unconstrained and often more unique?

I am seeking clarity on whether this process could lead to legal complications or falls within acceptable use. Thank you.

Is the wordlist, in whole, included in the part of the game which is distributed to players? E.g. if it is sold as a download, is the wordlist somewhere in that download? If it's playable on a website, is the wordlist accessed or accessible by the client? AFAIK, the question of whether an English language wordlist is copyrightable is so far untested in court, but at least most developers in the Scrabble community apparently believe they are at risk of lawsuit if they include copies of the NWL or CSW wordlists within downloadable games or study tools.

@kaya3 my mobile game is free with ads on playstore. i didn't extract WoW wordlist database and put it in my game. i only use the WoW Answers Site (not official) to generate anagram, like what i described in the post (process).

In the US, simple lists that were created automatically are generally not subject to copyright protection. For example, a list of anagrams can easily be generated by a computer by searching a full word list.
For a list to be copyrightable, there has to be some human creativity involved in the selection or ordering. Putting words in order alphabetically isn't creative; putting them together to form a haiku would be.
I'm not familiar with the games you mentioned, so I don't know how the words are selected or presented, so I'm not sure whether they would actually be protected.

I think so! To give you an idea of how these games work, they take a base word, like "TRAIN," and use its anagrams to create a level. You might get words like RAIN, RANT, or ART. But not all possible anagrams are included—some are left out (like vulgar words), and the games often include "bonus" words for extra points, which I don’t copy.
The chosen words are then arranged into a unique crossword-style grid for each level. Do you think the word list alone would meet the "creative" threshold for copyright? (I make the grid myself.)
Thank you!
